# Is "irrehensible" or "irrehensibly" a word?

Tags: grammaticality

I thought that irrehensible was a word like "morally irrehensible" would mean something so bad it is beyond forgiveness, or "irrehensibly damaged" would be damaged beyond hope of repair.

None of the dictionaries I've tried looking up this word in like it.  Am I spelling this wrong? Or thinking of a different word?

EDIT: If I google ["morally irrehensible"](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22morally+irrehensible%22) I get 75 results all being used as a really terrible act.  It says "did you mean [morally rehensible](http://www.google.com/search?q=%22morally+rehensible%22)" which gives 195 results all seeming to have the same meaning.  So it seems like every 3rd or 4th time this word is used, people incorrectly add in the "ir-".  Not sure why this is such a common mistake, but irrehensible is how I've always heard it.

Comment: I didn't find _irrehensible_ on the _New Oxford American Dictionary_.

Comment: *Rehensible* isn't a word either, as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think you mean *reprehensible* (deserving censure because it’s so bad). The antonym would be *irreprehensible* (deserving no censure).